# Javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, html, removechild

I have a UI, which when you press FIGHT it deletes the four currents divs FIGHT, STATUS, BLANK, BLANK2 and replaces them with new ones. This works except for the STATUS div. It brings up the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

and stops the other divs from deleting. When I take out the code removing the STATUS div `parent0.removeChild(status);` the code works correctly with the obvious exception of the STATUS div deleting.

I am utterly confused since those four divs are nested within a div named UI, and I assume the error is referring to the fact that STATUS isn't a child of UI? That shouldn't be the case. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

JSfiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/razorleaff/abks2dvq/3/
```

Comment: Where is `status` defined for `parent0.removeChild(status);` I don't see it being defined anywhere.

Comment: `status` is a javascript reserve word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing that way

```
parent0.removeChild(status);
```

is a bad practice, which causes problem like this,
since status is a javascript reserve word instead of doing that just do

```
parent0.removeChild(document.getElementById('status'));
```

> Definition and Usage
>   The removeChild() method removes a specified child node of the specified element.

Returns the removed node as a Node object, or null if the node does not exist.

```
 Parameter | Type | Description
  node        Node    object
```

Required. The node object you want to remove

[**Updated Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/abks2dvq/4/)

Comment: Your code fixes my problem. Thank you for also telling and showing me the proper way to use the removeChild(). I forgot completely about javascript reserve words.

Comment: `status` is not a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_keywords_as_of_ECMAScript_2015). As [Pig Ball's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43317786/778975) indicates, it is a property of the `window` object, which in the browser is the global object, making `status` a global variable that refers to [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `window` object has a property named [`status`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp) and you can't access status element via `id`. So, your code should be: *(always use `document.getElementById` to get an element using `id`)*

```
parent0.removeChild(document.getElementById('status'));
```

instead of:

```
parent0.removeChild(status);
```

Comment: Changing the id from status to something else fixed my problem thank you.